# Chang a value in a json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So i'm having a Json file as follow in vs code python:

```
{
    "matches_details":[
            { 
            "MatchID": "Liverpool-Manchester United",
            "Score": "5-0",
             "Date": "17/12/2020",
              "Time": "16:00",
               "Yellow cards": "2",
                "Red cards": "1",
                 "State": "FT"},
             { 
            "MatchID": "Crystal Palace-Chelsea",
                "Score": "3-2",
                "Date": "20/1/2021",
                "Time": "12:00",
                    "Yellow cards": "1",
                    "Red cards": "0",
                    "State": "HT"
                    }]
}
```

and i want to change the 'score' of a match, how can i do it?
here's what i tried, but unexecutable:

```
Time_client='12:00'
    Date_client='20/1/2021'
    Match_client='Crystal Palace-Chelsea'
    Score_client='10-0'
    f = open('datngu.json','r+')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    for item in data['matches_details']:
        if item['Name']==Match_client:
            if item['Time']==Time_client:
                if item['Date']==Date_client:
                    item['Score']=item['Score'].replace(Score_client,item['MatchID'])
    
    f2=open('datngu.json','r+')
    json.dump(data,f2)
    f2.close()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\DELL.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.2.633441544\json_reading.py", line 40, in 
updateScore()
File "c:\Users\DELL.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.2.633441544\json_reading.py", line 31, in updateScore
if item['Name']==Match_client:
KeyError: 'Name'

Comment: The error seems reasonably clear: you're trying to access a key named `Name`, but no such key exists in the example JSON you've posted in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to type `MatchID` instead of `name` as there is no `name` property in the JSON:

```
Time_client='12:00'
    Date_client='20/1/2021'
    Match_client='Crystal Palace-Chelsea'
    Score_client='10-0'
    f = open('datngu.json','r+')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    for item in data['matches_details']:
        if item['MatchID']==Match_client:
            if item['Time']==Time_client:
                if item['Date']==Date_client:
                    item['Score']=item['Score'].replace(Score_client,item['MatchID'])
    
    f2=open('datngu.json','r+')
    json.dump(data,f2)
    f2.close()
```

Comment: i'm so siily!Anyways, Thanks